# Asynctask not working with real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to fetch data in background from firebase real time database? `Asynctask` doesn't work with it.

I want to display progress dialog while fetching data from database.

```
 private class asyncData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Asycdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            Asycdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Query query = databaseReference.child("").orderByChild("cityWithCountry").equalTo(strings[0]);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    arrData.clear();
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
                        for (DataSnapshot items : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            // do something with the individual "issues"
                            Log.d("QueryValues",""+items.getValue());
                            DataConstructor ds = items.getValue(DataConstructor.class);
                            arrData.add(ds);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            return  null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Asycdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

here is the code.

Comment: Usually you should show the dialog in pre execute and dismiss in post execute . i dont know why this is not working can you please share your code

Comment: You can use `LiveData` to do some background task.

Comment: Can you post your AsyncTask please

Comment: posted code of AsyncTask

Comment: why you need Async task here?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput i want to show progress dialog while fetching all data.

Comment: @UmangBurman I'm not getting any error but progress dialog not showing that's the only problem i'm facing.

Comment: Kishan, Actually, dialog is showing and immediately getting dismissed. So you are not able to see the dialog box

Comment: @UmangBurman i'm checking log and log showing that it took 3-4 second to fetch records but not showing progress Dialog .

Comment: Okay, type `if (s != null) { Asycdialog.dismiss(); }` in your `onPostExecute()` and try, Now you can see your dialog going forever. Just try once, then i'll explain what's happening. Try the above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180502/discussion-between-kishan-and-umang-burman).

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it works or not.

```
   Asycdialog.show();
     Query query = databaseReference.child("").orderByChild("cityWithCountry").equalTo(strings[0]);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        arrData.clear();
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
                            for (DataSnapshot items : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                // do something with the individual "issues"
                                Log.d("QueryValues",""+items.getValue());
                                DataConstructor ds = items.getValue(DataConstructor.class);
                                arrData.add(ds);
**// check condition and hide your dialog here**
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: do you mean i put Asycdialog.show() inside doInBackground ?

Comment: No there is no need of asynctask

Comment: Thanks it's working great...

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote if you think it's helpful